# why both target framework and target android version are required?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

Target Framework – Specifies which framework to use in building your application. This API level is used at compile time by Xamarin.Android.

Target Android Version – Specifies the version of Android that your app is intended to run on. This API level is used at run time by Android.

If I had to use features of API 25(Android 7.1) in my app, it means that I should be setting the target framework (***compile***) to API 25 and isn't it obvious that it can ***run*** only on top of API 25.

Below are the three possibilities.

1. **Target Framework version lower than target android version** - Anything compiled on a lower
   version should be runnable on higher version. so what is use of
   capturing higher target version in this case.
2. **Target Framework version higher than target android version** - I don't see any use of it, if the app is compiled on higher version, it means the designated features will not run on the lower target android version.
3. **Target Framework version is same as target android version** - no complaints.

I might be totally wrong, please help me understand the real time use case for first two points.

Comment: The possibility to use a framework higher than the target android version allows you to create a single application which can change it's behavior depending on the device's android version.

Comment: @Gusman If the app can't leverage the features of higher version framework(due to lower target android version),then what is the point of compiling it using a higher version framework ?

Comment: Again, if you plan your app to support different targets you can offer different functionalities, if the device is of a lower type you can reduce the functionality, use a different UI with different controls and so on and on the higher devices increase the functionality, use a more modern UI, etc etc.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. The real question is why are there two upper bounds, not what is the purpose of an upper bound. You could have just one upper bound and still handle lower android versions, right? So why have two.